# Common way to switch fragments without loosing state

Tags: android, fragment

I am pretty new to android development so I am curious how to work properly with Fragments.

My application contains a `BottomNavigationActivity` which switches between 3 fragments with this code:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_montage_order_detail, fragment).commit();
```

I am storing the Fragments in a `List<Fragment>` to avoid loosing the current state. But everytime I replace the fragment with another the method `onDestroy()` is called.

I know, I know I could add and remove the fragment in the fragmentmanager instead of replacing it. I googled alot and most of the tutorials tell me to replace the fragment.

**Whats the common way to keep a fragments state without recreating it on every call?**

Comment: You can do addFragment.

Comment: do you have a view pager associated with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find the solution

It will not recreate fragment anytime

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.content_montage_order_detail, fragment).commit();
```

Comment: and later attach and detach it?

Answer (score 2):

Use fragment TAG at time of creation of fragment then when you want to get it again use findFragmentByTag. if fragment already created then old one will be find by fragment manager.

Fragment previousFragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("TAG");

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you use `show`,not for`replace`

```
protected void addFragmentStack(Fragment fragment) {
    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    if (this.mContent != fragment) {
        if (fragment.isAdded()) {
            ft.hide(this.mContent).show(fragment);
        } else {
            ft.hide(this.mContent).add(getFragmentViewId(), fragment);
        }
        this.mContent = fragment;
    }
    ft.commit();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using `switchFragment` to switch fragment, it will show fragment if it is already added.

Use `fragmentTransaction.show` method to re-use existing fragment i.e. saved instance.

```
public void switchFragment (Fragment oldFragment, Fragment newFragment, int frameId) {

    boolean addFragment = true;

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager ();
    String tag = newFragment.getArguments ().getString (BaseFragment.TAG);
    Fragment fragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag (tag);

    // Check if fragment is already added
    if (fragment != null && fragment.isAdded ()) {
        addFragment = false;
    }

    // Hide previous fragment
    String oldFragmentTag = oldFragment.getArguments ().getString (BaseFragment.TAG);

    if (!tag.equals (oldFragmentTag)) {
        FragmentTransaction hideTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction ();
        Fragment fragment1 = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag (oldFragmentTag);
        hideTransaction.hide (fragment1);
        hideTransaction.commit ();
    }

    // Add new fragment and show it
    FragmentTransaction addTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction ();

    if (addFragment) {
        addTransaction.add (frameId, newFragment, tag);
        addTransaction.addToBackStack (tag);
    }
    else {
        newFragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag (tag);
    }

    addTransaction.show (newFragment);

    addTransaction.commit ();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ya, you can also manage the state by managing the **backstack**.